# Who offers CO2 Laser treatment for Bartholin's Cysts in California?

Tags: treatment, treatment-options, laser

I've called a very large number of GYN surgical clinics in and around the bay area and none of them seem to offer this treatment.

Any leads are much appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because other than a few specific SE sites, "recommend me X" or "find me Y" type questions are not allowed on the SE system.

Answer (score 1):

I found a lead that may provide you with a practitioner in California that offers the treatment you are looking for.

> MISforWomen.com provides patients with complete access to AAGL’s Physician Finder, a comprehensive database of our more than 7,500 members.  Finding a surgeon who specializes in minimally invasive surgery has never been easier with this excellent, easy-to-use physician search engine.
>
> AAGL – Advancing Minimally Invasive Gynecology Worldwide
> 6757 Katella Avenue | Cypress, CA 90630
> (800) 554-2245 | (714) 503-6200

https://www.aagl.org/jmig/journal-spotlight-co2-laser-treatment-for-bartholin-gland-abscess-ultrasound-evaluation-of-risk-recurrence-2/

https://www.aagl.org/service/patient-outreach/